# using scala-meta, how to infer types

Tags: scalameta

I would like to be able to detect the full type name of a type T when it is referred within some other compilation unit A. So say A is

```
package p

import com.p1.A
import com.p2._

class X {
  def method1:A // detect it as com.p1.A, which I can do because of the import
  def method2:B // detect it as com.p2.B, which I can't at the moment
}
```

I get the feeling that scalameta probably is not the best tool for type detection, is there a safe/easy way to detect all types?